# reachability of the norm by the operator

Tags: functional-analysis, normed-spaces

$A: \ell^1 \to \mathbb{R}$, where $$Ax= \sum\limits_{k=0}^\infty((2+\cos(\pi(1/3)^{k+1})\xi_{k+1}).$$

\begin{aligned}
||Ax||_{\mathbb{R}} &= |Ax| = |(2+\cos(\pi(1/3))\xi_1) + (2+\cos(\pi(1/9))\xi_2)+(2+\cos(\pi(1/27))\xi_3) + \dots| \\
&\leq |(2+\cos(\pi(1/3))\xi_1)|+|(2+\cos(\pi(1/9))\xi_2)|+|(2+\cos(\pi(1/27))\xi_3)|+\dots \\
&\leq 3|\xi_1|+3|\xi_2|+3|\xi_3|+\dots \\
&=3||x||_{\ell^1}
\end{aligned}

I have already shown the limit, but I can't prove that the norm is not reached.

Answer (score 3):

In fact, the fact that $\ell^1$'s dual is $\ell^\infty$ reminds us that $||A|| = \sup_{k \in \mathbb{N} \cup \{0\}} |2 + \cos(\pi/3^{k+1})| = 3$.
It's a routine exercise to show that for all $\epsilon > 0$, there exists $x \in \ell^1$ such that $||Ax|| > (3-\epsilon)||x||_1$, so that $3-\epsilon$ can't be the operator norm.  It's impossible to find a vector that satisfies the equality case in this Hölder's inequality $|\langle v,x \rangle|_1 \le ||v||_\infty ||x||_1$ with $v = (2 + \cos(\pi/3^{k+1}))_{k\in\mathbb{N}\cup\{0\}}$ and $x = (\xi_k)_k$ because in the equality case, $v$ and $x$ have to be linearly dependent (i.e. $v = kx$), but $v \notin \ell^1$ while $x \in \ell^1$.